# JPA, Hibernate : Database Schema

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

This is my first post, so hi everybody! :)

I have a question regarding a schema of my database. I'm writing RESTful application using Spring. The idea is to allow user to create his own diet based on products stored in DB.

So I came to creating entity Meal, which should consist of Products and amount of those products. It seems like natural way to have something like this is using Map. Problem is, that as I have read there is a problem with mapping such class to JSON Object, which I would like to send to clients browser. My other idea was to store List of objects like ProductWithQuantity instead of such map, but I'm a little worried that DB would be quickly flooded by entries like 1 glass of milk, 2 glasses of milk, 1.1243 glasses of milk and so on.

So my question is - do you have any better idea for the schema for such purpose? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would define an entity Meal which has a oneToMany relation to an entity Product, this product has properties like 'name', 'amount' and 'unit' and 'price' or something like that. Unit can be "gramm", "liter" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest a Meal with many servings, each serving being of a single product.  Products like Milk or Hamburg are likely to have nutritional information, while a Meal will have many servings of different products.  Serving would essentially be a relational table between Mean and Product, but with additional information like serving size.

```
@Entity
Class Meal {
  @Id
  Integer Id;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="meal")
  List<Serving> servings;
}

@Entity
Class Serving {
  @Id
  Integer Id;
  @OneToOne
  Meal meal;
  @OneToOne
  Product product;
  @Basic
  Long servingCount;
}

@Entity
Class Product {
  @Id
  Integer Id;
  @Basic
  String simpleName;
  @Basic
  Integer caloriesPerServing;
  ..
}
```